# Display List Items in a label using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

Hey guys I have been stuck on this issue for a couple of days. I have two list boxes that a user can transfer data back and forth between. I need the items that are in the listbox on the right to also display in a label located in a table below the listboxes.

I have gotten the text to display in the label but I can not get it to enter a new line for each item (like they would display in the listbox). The text is coming up with spaces and still doesn't split on a new line. I am fairly new to javascript so please be kind :)

Here is my javascript:

```
    function displayLabel()
            {
                var item = document.getElementById("lstRightBox").options.innerText;
                var arr = new Array();
                var test = item.split(arr.join("|"));
                document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = test.join("\r\n");
                return true;
            }
```

**ADDED**

Here is the code that transfers the items inbetween the listboxes:

```
    // This moves selected items
    function move_list_items(lstLeftBox, lstRightBox)
      {
        $("#"+lstLeftBox+"  option:selected").appendTo("#"+lstRightBox).toString;
      }

      //this will move all items 
    function move_list_items_all(lstLeftBox, lstRightBox)
      {
        $("#"+lstLeftBox+" option").appendTo("#"+lstRightBox);
      }
```

**EDIT**

Here is an update to my display function. I am calling it in my move functions (listed above) so that it is executed each time a button is clicked. I am currently getting [object Object] displaying in my label for each item moved.

```
    function displayLabel(lstLeftBox, lstRightBox)
          {
            $("#"+lstRightBox+"  option").each(function(){
                document.getElementById("label").innerHTML += $(this);
            });
          }
```

Comment: Maybe you should add <br/> after \n

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML? Bonus points if you create a quick demo at jsfiddle.net.

Comment: The <br/> puts every letter on a new line.

Comment: I'm not sure that the HTML would help much. It's built as a string in vb.net. I use a With statement to populate the left listbox then buttons inbetween to transfer data over to the rightbox. But if it will help I can try and get it on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a way to get the items to display correctly! What I did was made a few changes to my original displayLabel() function listed above. I used a for loop to look through my options that were in my right list box. The code is listed below for anyone who may find it helpful.

```
            function displaylabel()
                {
                    var lstBox = document.getElementById("lstRightListBox").options.innerText;
                    var label = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("lstRightListBox").options.length; i++)
                        {
                            label += document.getElementById("lstRightListBox").options(i).text + '<br>';
                        }
                    document.getElementById("label ").innerHTML = label;
                }
```

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted out. Just FYI, this is literally doing the same thing as the final version of the jQuery I was iterating on with you. Neither is better or worse, but they do exactly the same things (save that this saves the intermediate processing to local variables along the way).

Comment: Ah okay. I don't know why I couldn't get it to work! But thank you for pointing that out to me. It's good to know for future reference. I just couldn't get it to break out on a new line after I got the words to display. Thank you again though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused on your use of `split()` and `join()`. As written, the code isn't splitting by the presence of `"|"` but rather splitting on every character. That's because there are no values in the array on which you are calling `.join()`.

I think this will do what you're looking for:

```
    function displayLabel()
        {
            var item = document.getElementById("lstRightBox").options.innerText;
            var test = item.split("|");
            document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = test.join("\r\n<br/>");
            return true;
        }
```

#### Here's a breakdown for how that works:

- I am assuming that your values from the `lstRightBox` are separated by `|`.
- The line `var test = item.split("|");` creates an array in the `test` variable, with each element of the array being a different value from the `item` string (where each value is separated by `|`).
- Then the line after it puts the output of `test.join("\r\n<br/>")` into the HTML of the `label` element, where the output of `test.join("\r\n<br/>")` is a string wherein each item is separated by `"\r\n<br/>"`.

Note that I added the `<br/>` back in there so that it will put display a line break between each matching item from `test`.

It is also worth noting that you could probably accomplish the same thing using [`.replace()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp):

```
    function displayLabel()
        {
            var items = document.getElementById("lstRightBox").options.innerText;
            document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = items.replace("|", "\r\n<br/>");
            return true;
        }
```

**Edit:** Looking at the code you are using to move the items, I think you can do something similar here. Instead of doing the replace() or .join(), you can rely on the same jQuery selectors that you are already using:

```
// selected items
function display_list_items(lstBox)
  {
    $("#"+lstBox+"  option:selected").each(function(){
        document.getElementById("label").innerHTML += $(this);
    });
  }

  // all items 
function display_list_items_all(lstComplete, lstRightBox)
  {
    $("#"+lstBox+"  option").each(function(){
        document.getElementById("label").innerHTML += $(this);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for breaking down how it works! It's always nice to know the how behind the code. But it's not working right. I think it's I don't have anything separating the items. I think they are all coming through as one big clump of items without anything separating them out. I'm guessing that has to do with how they are being transferred over. I'll post that code.

Comment: It likely has less to do with how they are transferred over and more to do with how they are listed in the first place. You're exactly right that this won't work if you don't have a `|` separating the items. You need some kind of a separator. That might currently be there in the form of `\r\n` (or something similar), and you could easily use that instead of the `|` in the code I had above. You probably want to remove `\r\n` from the `.join()` and/or `.replace()` function calls (and just leave `<br/>`).

Comment: To figure out what is currently used as separation character(s), it may be as simple as viewing the source on the initial page. You'll need to examine in a program that allows you to see the actual characters employed for new line (if a new line is the separater). Though if it's new line, you could also end up doing something like `items.replace("\r\n", "<br/>").replace("\r", "<br/>").replace("\n","<br/>");` to cover most situations pretty well.

Comment: When I viewed the source It had all the items from the database listed in between <option></option> I can't tell how the lines are being separated other then that. What are some examples of a program I would need to see that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: After taking another look at how you are moving the items, I think you can use a similar methodology based on jQuery selectors. See my edit above.

Comment: I'm still getting nothing :( I have added the code that you suggested to my display function. See my EDIT.

Comment: Depending on which of your move methods actually worked, you might need to add .toString()

Comment: I am using your display_list_items_all(lstLeftBox, lstRightBox), but I did try both and they both give me the same results [object Object]. I'm beginning to wonder if I should try to find a javascript way to move my items.. then I think I would be able to use the split or join methods.

Comment: Right... The fact that it is an object makes me think that the function you are using to move them had .toString (in the code that you posted, one  function did and one did not). So I believe adding .toString may be the way to get to the text below the object. If that doesn't work, you might also try .val() or .html()

Comment: the .toString() did not work. Adding the .val() after the $(this) gave me the index of the item so I tried $(this).html() and that did show me the text. But now it is a big mess. When I click the buttons it counts everything in the right list box and readds it to the label. So I am getting tons of repeats.
Before with my javascript they were only displaying once.

Comment: Add a line at the beginning of the function to clear the current content.  Something like document.getElementById("label").innerHTML="";

Comment: @JefferyBlake thank you for all your help. I finally figured out a solution to my problem.